# Google Play service approach get back camera

Tags: android

I just recently got Google Play services installed and it has broken some of my code.

The following code is broken now:

```
/**
 * get back camera facing id (non google play services approach)
 * @return camera id (-1 if not found)
 */
private int getCameraFacingBack() {
    int cameraId = -1;
    // get the number of cameras
    int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    // check all cameras
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
        CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
        if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
            cameraId = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return cameraId;
}
```

Anyway to get the back camera via a Google Play service way? These are the two emulator images:
[image]

The top image works.

Comment: I am not aware that anything in Play Services has anything to do with cameras, nor should anything in the Play Services SDK cause a change in how `Camera` works. What specifically is not working for you here?

Comment: Google Play services has nothing to do with the camera. How has your code actually been broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a long night. I forgot to add my webcam as a camera on the Google API image emulator. DOH.